# Email Attachment from memory stream is coming as blank in C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, email-attachments, memorystream

I am able to send an attachment in a mail but the attachment content is blank and size is being shown as 0 bytes.

After doing some search over the internet found that we need to reset the memory stream position to 0 in order to start from start.

I tried that as well but it seems it is not working. Can you please help?

Please find below my code snippet:

NOTE: I am able to save the workbook and Data is present in the saved workbook.

```
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
        writer.Write(xlWorkbook);
        writer.Flush();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtpclient");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("To@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Entry";
        mail.Body = "Hello, PFA ";
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;

        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(memoryStream,"xls");
        attachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Input" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhss") + ".xls";
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        SmtpServer.Port = 465;
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Username", "password");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        writer.Dispose();
```

Comment: Do you know that the XLS file is being properly read? What is the position after the flush?

Comment: Position value after the flush is 44

Comment: Last diagnostic question, what happens if you Seek to 0 rather than Position = 0? Like memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

Comment: I tried that as well , still i am getting the same blank attachment in the email.

Comment: Check tranquil tarn answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336239/how-to-attach-a-file-from-memorystream-to-a-mailmessage-in-c-sharp You need to use stream.Position = 0;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the attachment is confusing the mail system. Microsoft's recommendation is to specify the content type as an [octet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Below is a replacement for initializing the attachment. The reset of your code looks fine.

```
string filename = "Input" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhss") + ".xls";
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(memoryStream, filename, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710677/email-attachment-from-the-memorystream-comes-empty?rq=1