# Attachment start missing in an Email after a period of time

Tags: c#, email-attachments

I am having issues with the attachment in an email. After every few days, user don't find the expected attachment in there email. This seems to be happening for around 10-20 mins and then it corrected itself meaning that the later email will contain the attachments. I am not sure what could be the reason behind this. This is how my code looks like

**Model**

```
public class EmailAttachment
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileContent { get; set; }
}
```

**Code trigger to send an Email**

```
var emailAttachment= new EmailAttachment();
emailAttachment.FileContent = CreatePDFFile();
emailAttachment.FileName = "file.pdf";
EmailGeneratedCertificate(emailAttachment);
```

**Email Preparation Code**

```
public void EmailGeneratedCertificate(EmailAttachment file)
{
    //file.FileContent is a byte array  
    var ms = new MemoryStream(file.FileContent);
    ms.Position = 0;
    var contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);

    var from = "xx@x.com";
    var fromTargetName = "XXX";
    var recepient="xx2@x.com"
    var subject = "Attachment";
    var body="<strong>Please find attachment.</strong>"
    var attachment = new Attachment(ms, contentType);
    attachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = file.FileName;
    var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    attachments.Add(attachment);
    _mailService.Send(recepient, null, subject, body, attachments);
}
```

Another thing I wanted to point out, I have two websites running within a different `APP POOL` and both have the same email sending code like above and when this issue occur, it seems to be happening on both websites at same time for 10-15 mins and then corrected itself. Please suggest.

Comment: *“After a period of time (4-5 days), user don't find the expected attachment in there email.”* — let them try harder. Mailboxes work **independent of** your email sending code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Can you please explain?

Comment: Is there any issue in my code? Email send fine just have an issue with the attachment. Could be a memory related issue? Not sure.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the attachments are always getting added to the email? Just to make sure, you could add this before the email is sent: mailMessage.Body += "There are " + mailMessage.Attachments.Count() + " attachment(s) to this email.";

Comment: Yes they always added to the email. Just automatically stop working after certain period and sometime it start working again. Acting strange!

Comment: Are you saying that the attachments stop getting sent after 4-5 days, and start getting sent again after you restart IE?  Or is it that the attachments in already-sent emails are appearing and disappearing?

Comment: Yes, they get an email but don't find any attachment. Sometime I need to recycle the IIS and sometime it automatically start getting sent.

Comment: For example, yesterday they stop getting sent from 12:30pm to 2:00pm CST and then start getting sent again.

Comment: And what *exactly* is in the mails that don't have the expected attachment? Do you have any of these emails yourself? You should look at one as closely as possible.

Comment: Yes, I have those emails as I cc'd them to admin email as well. The body of the email is always there, just the attachment is not there.

Comment: @JonSkeet Any suggestion you would like to purpose?

Comment: Well I would look at the headers *very, very carefully*. Compare the headers of a working one to a broken one. Check the path, whether it's gone through spam filters etc.

Comment: I couldn't find a single difference in the working and broken one. The broken one still goes in inbox but it doesn't have an attachment which is quite weird. It just happened half an hour back and then automatically corrected itself.

Comment: @JonSkeet After a lot of effort, I figured out the attachment actually get sent to the customer but as I mentioned it also get cc'd to admin email. So it is actually missing in the cc'd email, not the customer one. Any thoughts why it start missing in the cc'd email?

Comment: Sounds like the mail server is stripping it off - at the sending point it's just one email.

Comment: Usually it is there every time. Any thoughts why mail server stripping it off for few mins once in a while?

Answer (score 3):

In your question you don't write all the code of `CreatePDFFile()` that IMHO is the cause of the strange behavior so I can only guess from the code you post.

I see 2 main problem:

1. `private byte[] ReadFile(string path)`: you are swallowing any exception and if there are some it returns an empty byte array so no attachment.
2. `MemoryStream` in `EmailGeneratedCertificate(EmailAttachment file)`: you are not disposing the stream and this could case some unexpected behavior

Comment: Thanks for pointing those, I will add catch block in the first one and log any exception that may occur. For the 2nd one, can you let me know how would I dispose the memory steam? If I dispose in `EmailGeneratedCertificate(EmailAttachment file)` I no longer receive an email

Comment: @AmmarKhan You should dispose the memorystream after the email is sent:put it into using statement that close after _mailService.Send...

Comment: If you notice my email code run on a separate thread, do you still think it will close the memory stream after the email sent?

Comment: @AmmarKhan mhh I did not notice. why don't you use `SmtpClient.SendAsync`? anyway to dispose the stream with async call you should rewrite that part of your code. the easiest way could be to  join the 2 methods

Comment: will you be able to update my email code to address the necessary changes?

Comment: @AmmarKhan better idea: just dispose the `MailMessage` object after sending the mail. it will take care of the memory stream

Comment: That sounds good. So that should be right after like `SmtpClient.Send(mailMessage);` `MailMessage.Dispose();`

Comment: @AmmarKhan better to use using statement that close after the other using statement where client.Send(mailMessage) is in.

Comment: OK. Can you please check my email code one more time? I just updated as you said.

Comment: Another think, I may have to point our. I have two websites running in parallel which uses the same code base with minimal changes but for this particular functionality the code is same. Both uses there own App Pool, the interesting thing which I noticed, the issue occur on both sites at the same time.

Comment: @AmmarKhan Let us continue this discussion in chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103832/discussion-between-giammin-and-ammar-khan

Comment: Are you still there to help me fix this. I am still struggling with this issue. Even though I put a logging in a try catch block in each section of my code related to this email. But surprising it does not log any thing when the email get sent out without any attachment.